# In macOS, installing Homebrew from clean install returns an error

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install brew on my mac (intel), I'm using this command (from the homepage of Brew https://brew.sh/):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

And it returns the following error:

```
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).
Password:
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R User:admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
error: Could not read 02f0189335907805d422c817462674081f48ab60
error: Could not read 7e455a623a3f49f63b589ea31d72c860b1d33c06
error: Could not read 02f0189335907805d422c817462674081f48ab60
error: Could not read 7e455a623a3f49f63b589ea31d72c860b1d33c06
remote: Enumerating objects: 111915, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (107893/107893), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (25395/25395), done.
remote: Total 107053 (delta 81151), reused 104985 (delta 79221), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (107053/107053), 28.88 MiB | 6.37 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas:  99% (81133/81151), completed with 618 local objects.
fatal: pack has 18 unresolved deltas
fatal: index-pack failed
Failed during: git fetch --force origin
```

It doesn't give me any hint of possible follow-up actions. What should I do?

Let me know if I should post any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of wandering around forums and GitHub issues, and StackOverflow answers long gone forgotten, I finally made it!

I solved it by removing my `/usr/local/Homebrew` folder and then reinstalling homebrew from scratch with the command from their website (https://brew.sh/).

*Now, I would love to give credit to whom I got this solution from, but I can't find the link among all the tabs and docs I had open. Maybe one day...*

Comment: Should mark this as the correct answer, I struggled with this - even after doing the guided 'complete brew removals' online.